# Character encoding in Java not working

Tags: java, string, encoding, character

I am currently working on a program that basically translates between English and Russian. However, when entering a Russian word, some of the characters are not encoded properly.

For example, 'привет', works fine but for 'яблоко', I get: '�?блоко' after encoding.

The code I have for the encoding is:

```
String s = new String(searchText.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(s);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"UTF-8" is specifying that the String you are receiving is in UTF-8 format. Most likely it is in a different format.

If you use the correct encoding it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the necessary encoding setup on your console. If you are on windows command prompt, execute first-

> chcp 65001 && start.bat

If you are using Eclipse, do-

> Run Configuration -> Common-> Encoding -> Other -> UTF-8